# surefire-report adding input data to the report

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying this brillian maven plugin to produce test reports.
The problem I'm having is that I'm using the `Parameterized` class to add inputs. So now my report looks like this:

```
testAuth[0] 0.411
testAuth[1] 0.353
testAuth[2] 0.385
testAuth[3] 0.388
testAuth[4] 0.514
```

Instead I would like to have the input data shown. Is there a way to do it?

Here's the screenshot

[image]

Comment: What is what in your report? Data and result? Also, where do you see such text? In `-output.txt` file?

Comment: The html report created by surefire-report. Wait I'll give you a screenshot.

Comment: I don't have html reports, only txt. Did you configure anything in surefire plugin settings?

Comment: html reports are made with this command: -e -Denv=test clean install site surefire-report:report